# Apply function only on woocommerce (date update)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

there is a way to apply this function only on woocommerce post type?

```
function reset_post_date_wpse_121565($data,$postarr) {
// var_dump($data,$postarr); die; // debug
$data['post_date'] = $data['post_modified'];
$data['post_date_gmt'] = $data['post_modified_gmt'];
return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','reset_post_date_wpse_121565',99,2);
```

I need to reset only woocommerce product after update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for wp_insert_post_data filter, just compare the post type to the cpt.

```
function reset_post_date_wpse_121565($data,$postarr) {

   if($data['post_type'] !== 'product')
        return $data;

   $data['post_date'] = $data['post_modified'];
   $data['post_date_gmt'] = $data['post_modified_gmt'];
   return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','reset_post_date_wpse_121565',99,2);
```

Comment: I forgot to write a piece of the function, I have now updated, sorry